# Message box that tells me which items on my list are missing data if any

Tags: vba, excel

Dear all: I'm working on a worksheet with 19 columns. I have my item name in column A. If the value in column S (Box quantity) is = 0 (zero) for any of the items.I would like the message box to tell me which items were they on a list, or simply written on the message box. That way I can go straight to the item  and insert the correct data.

e.g. Please note that the following items have zero box quantity:

- Trouser A/L
- Wine FS3

I know how to create a message box. However I don't know how to formulate the logic. Could anyone please help me?
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I got one for you.

```
Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
Dim row As Integer
Dim itemList As String

'Set your data sheet
Set dataSheet = Sheet1

row = 1

'We can't know how many row. So, I check only blank cell for item name.
'If not sufficient, tell me more.
Do While dataSheet.Range("A" & row) <> ""

    'If quantity is 0 or empty, add to list
    If dataSheet.Range("S" & row) = 0 Or dataSheet.Range("S" & row) = "" Then

        If itemList <> "" Then
            itemList = itemList & vbNewLine
        End If

        itemList = itemList & "Row: " & row & ", " & "Item: " & dataSheet.Range("A" & row)

    End If

    row = row + 1

Loop

'Show list in MsgBox
If itemList <> "" Then

    Call MsgBox("The following item(s) have no Qty:" & vbNewLine & itemList, vbInformation, "Checking Item Quantity")

End If
```

Comment: What is the difference between my code(below) and yours(above)? except you have added row number to the message?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is spot on what in need. However, when I set the data sheet name MEG and run the code it comes with an error "Object Error". Do you know why? many thanks

Comment: Also values in the Box quantity column,  "S" are the results of a vlookup. Will this still work?

Comment: If you want to set your sheet with sheet name , pls use as follow `Set dataSheet = ThisWorkBook.worksheets("MEG")`. Else set default sheet name "Sheet1" or "Sheet2" which is shown as (Name) in properties view. Yes, vlookup values can work.

Comment: 99moorem - Your code is right for a way. But you use `for` loop. It can harm application. You have no break point for your code and loop for all row in work sheet. So, I use `Do While` for it. I created it for code clear and easily understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Below should work. Change Activesheet if it is not working on the activesheet

```
Sub t()

With ActiveSheet
    For Each cell In .Range("A1:" & .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Address)
        If cell.Offset(0, 18).Value = 0 Or IsEmpty(cell.Offset(0, 18).Value) Then
            Temp = Temp & cell.Value & ", "
        End If
    Next
End With

if Temp <> "" then MsgBox "The following have no Qty :" & Left(Temp, Len(Temp) - 2)

End Sub
```